# VBA Input Box Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input box in my macro that is in a loop.  The numbers `1-4` correspond to a specific task that the program will do, and `5` will save and exit the program.

Right now, the input box is in a continuous loop unless the user types in `5`.  However, I would also like the loop and sub to end if the user hits `Cancel` or the `X` button in the upper-right corner of the input box.  When I hit `Cancel` or `X`, it gives me an error.

In summary, is it possible to code the `Cancel` and `X` keys of the input box to end the loop and exit the sub without an error message?  For example, this is what I have if the user types `6`:

```
If ipAnswer = 6 then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Is there something that would allow me to do:

```
If 'cancel' or 'x' then
    .......
End If
```

Comment: Dim the var that gets the return from the [InputBox method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768%28v=office.11%29.aspx) as a variant. If the variant is equal to "False" (as a string) then you can exit. Actually, I believe it can also be *False* as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect all three possible results when using `InputBox()` to return a string. Those three results are:

1. The user entered a value
2. The user clicked `[OK]` without entering a value
3. The user clicked `[Cancel]` or `[X]`

The `StrPtr()` function is the key to differentiating between a blank string and a nonexistent one. The following code demonstrates how to identify each scenario:

```
Dim s As String
s = InputBox("Enter something:")

If StrPtr(s) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "[Cancel] or [X] clicked"
ElseIf Len(s) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "[OK] clicked but nothing entered"
Else
    Debug.Print "Something entered: " & s
End If
```